# Why when I write to stderr I see STDERR output on the stdout?

Tags: python, stdout, stderr

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdout.write("STDOUT\n")
    sys.stderr.write("STDERR\n")
```

Could you explain why when I write to stderr I see STDERR output on the stdout? I supposed only STDOUT should be visible in the terminal.

```
$ python stdout_stdin.py
STDOUT
STDERR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I supposed only STDOUT should be visible in the terminal.

Incorrect. stderr is a separate file descriptor, but it's still connected to the same tty as stdout by default.

Answer (score 1):

Both stdout and stderr streams are connected  with your display device, by default, that's why you are seeing syserr messages on the screen also.

Answer (score 1):

Normally `stdout` and `stderr` are displayed in the terminal. If your OS supports it you can redirect one or both to elsewhere. For example you could redirect `stdout` and you would only see `stderr` in the terminal (or you could redirect `stderr` and you would only see `stdout` in the terminal).

Comment: @Leopoldo No, that would (in POSIX at least) means that `stdout` and `stderr` becomes the same stream and you would see both (or none).